# undefined keyword in javascript

Tags: javascript, undefined

I'm reading the ECMA-262 and see the following:

```
PrimaryExpression :
    this 
    Identifier 
    Literal 
    ArrayLiteral 
    ObjectLiteral 
    ( Expression )
Literal ::
    NullLiteral 
    BooleanLiteral 
    NumericLiteral 
    StringLiteral 
    RegularExpressionLiteral
```

As we can see there is no `undefined` in the PrimaryExpression defenition. So, how does `undefined` is evaluating and to what type of expression it belongs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) is not a keyword. It is a global read-only variable which represents the value undefined. This means it falls under the category of **Identifier** as listed under **PrimaryExpression** in your list.

Comment: Did you mean that `undefined` is evalueated as just identifier such that the result of evaluation is undefined?

Comment: And you don't ask my question. To what type of expression `undefined` is belong? Is it a literal as null literal? If yes why in ECMA-262 there is no "undefined literal" definition?

Comment: @St.Antario I clarified my answer.

Comment: It is not obviously that undefined is just identifier. Assume that it's true. Hence during the undefined identifier is resolving we're trying to find a corresponding binding like the `undefined-->some_value` in the  LexicalEnvironment of current execution context. Did you mean that every LexicalEnvironment of contains binding `undefined--->value`?

Comment: Oh I'm now understand your answer. Thank you.

Comment: @St.Antario Yes, undefined is a property of the global object, just like the function `eval()`, for example. Being read-only means that you can't change its value. You can, however, shadow the global variable `undefined` with a local `var undefined` (which would certainly be a bad idea, though).