# Why is undefined not writable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, typeof

According to [MDN's documentation on `undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined):

> In modern browsers (JavaScript 1.8.5 / Firefox 4+), undefined is a non-configurable, non-writable property per the ECMAScript 5 specification. Even when this is not the case, avoid overriding it.

One of the property attributes of *undefined* is that is not writable.

But if I do:

```js
var undefined = 'hello';
var test = undefined;
console.log(typeof test);
//string
```

Does that mean that I can overwrite the value of `undefined`? What happens if someone does that? Should JavaScript warn about that?

Comment: can you tell us which browser you use ? (Firefox 72.0b10 (64 bits) on Linux works as intended with `typeof test === "undefined"`)

Comment: Of course typeof  test returns string, it always returns string, it has nothing to do with overwriting

Comment: @DmitryReutov `typeof undefined` returns `"undefined"` under normal circumstances.

Comment: @Amy "undefined" is not a string? Is it number or what?

Comment: @DmitryReutov Of course `"undefined"` is a string.  The question is not asking what `typeof (typeof undefined)` evaluates to.  It's asking what `typeof undefined` evaluates to.  It returns `"undefined"`, not `"string"`

Comment: @Amy, it doesnt evaluate to anythin, that code works absolutely predictably, it returns string "undefined" or i misunderstood question

Comment: @DmitryReutov `typeof ______` is an expression that evaluates to a string containing the type of the `______`.  You are misunderstanding the question.

Comment: @Amy I think Demitry is using Edge, because it does return a string, on Chrome it returns `undefined`

Comment: @AlonEitan The `typeof` operator always returns a string.

Comment: @Amy I know, but Edge return "string" and Chrome "undefined"

Comment: Is there any practical application for monkey-patching it? To be precise, that's `window.undefined`.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

A removed comment by [Amy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/47589/amy) gives the solution. You are creating a variable named `undefined`, and it doesn't work if you do your snippets in the global scope:

```js
var undefined = 'hello';
var test = undefined;
console.log(typeof test);
```

But it effectively works if you do it in a local scope where *undefined* doesn't refer to the global variable anymore:

```js
(()=>{
  var undefined = 'hello';
  var test = undefined;
  console.log(typeof test);
})()
```

To prevent this mistake, you can use the `'use strict';` directive:

```js
'use strict';
var undefined = 'hello';
var test = undefined;
console.log(typeof test);
```

If you are writing code where you can't control where it will be executed (e.g. library, embed, etc) it is a good pattern to use a IIFE which makes it so you can guarantee that undefined will always be correct/usable. Here is an example:

```js
(function(undefined){
  // undefined will equal `undefined` because we didn't pass in an argument to the IIFE
  
  console.log(undefined); // always `undefined`, even if undefined !== `undefined`outside of the IIFE scope
})(); // No argument supplied
```

---

All my tests were made using Firefox 72.0b10 (64 bits) on Ubuntu, and the result for the first snippet may differ on an older browser.

Comment: @pmiranda not mine, found it very interesting

Comment: Thanks again. All this doubt has an origin in this: a new developer here was translating some spanish name variables to english. In our code, we had a variable called `let indefinido= dataArray( (a) => (anotherArray.includes(someName)));` we were checking if that var were 'undefined' (the result of `find` with no elements found) or not. Then he translate `indefinido` to `undefined` I saw that I test it on Chrome and Edge, seeing some difference. That's why I came here to ask the opinion of the rest, because I'm learning too.

Comment: @pmiranda This answer doesn't strictly answer the "why" part. But it is a good answer.

Comment: If you end up needing the actual value of undefined, use `void 0`

Comment: Why are you able to create a variable named undefined? You can't make one called `var` or `true`

Comment: @Jon because for [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22152598/undefined-keyword-in-javascript) [reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173773/why-nan-and-undefined-are-not-reserved-keywords-in-javascript) the Ecmascript Consortium chosed not to make undefined a [reserved keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords) but a property of the global object

Answer (score 18):

> While it is possible to use it as an identifier (variable name) in any
> scope other than the global scope (because undefined is not a reserved
> word), doing so is a very bad idea that will make your code difficult
> to maintain and debug.

Source https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined

`undefined` is **not reserved** hence it is possible to assign it a new value.

When you are not using `strict mode` you are essentially creating a variable called `undefined` in local scope and assigning a `string` value to it.

[**`undefined` is a property of the global object**](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.1). The initial value of undefined is the primitive value `undefined`.

`use strict` will help prevent this mistake in global scope while it can still be overwritten in local scope.

If you want to be more safe you should use `void 0` instead of `undefined`
which always returns `undefined`.

```js
'use strict'

const test = (() => {
  let undefined = "test"
  console.log(typeof undefined)
  console.log(typeof void 0)
})()
```

Comment: here's the [keyword list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords) for more details

Comment: Worth noting that in such an IIFE one can also get a reference to `undefined` by reading it as an argument. As the IIFE is never passed any arguments here they will be `undefined` within it. E.g. `((undefined) => console.log(typeof undefined))()`